# App Delegate - page controller error

Tags: ios, swift

I am unsure what I have done wrong with this statement below. I have added a page view controller to my project but when I build and run the project I get a 'bool' error. Here is the code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)

    let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not returned the statement, you either need to return true or false. I think you have forgot to `return true`. Try using the code below:

```
    let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return true
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks That has solved it! I must have deleted it when I added the page control doh!

Answer (score 1):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)

    let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks That has solved it! I must have deleted it when I added the page control doh!